# Why is John Wick gifted with a new car?

Tags: plot-explanation, john-wick

In *John Wick*, at the time of vacating the Continental, John Wick is gifted with new car.

Why did the hotel people gift him that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## As compensation

John Wick was nearly killed when Ms Perkins broke the rules of the Continental by trying to do so on the grounds of the hotel.

He's given the car as an apology of sorts for the hotel allowing that to happen.

> When fellow professional (Adrianne Palicki) tries to kill Wick on the grounds of the Continental—thus breaking the rules—hotel owner Winston (Ian McShane) gives Wick a 2011 Dodge Charger SRT as compensation:
>
> > “A parting gift. From the management.”
>
> [Link](https://www.hagerty.com/articles-videos/articles/2019/05/14/john-wick-is-classic-american-action-including-the-cars)